# JUnit Test With More than One Accepted Answer

Tags: java, junit, junit4, assert

Is it possible to have multiple accepted answers in a JUnit test? So for example:

```
   Main rock = new Main();
   Assert.assertEquals("y", boxes("23"));
```

So for this test I want to be able to accept the result string "y" or "n" as an acceptable answer, is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Hamcrest CoreMatcher (included in JUnit 4.4 and later) and assertThat():

```
Assert.assertThat(boxes("23"), anyOf(is("y"), is("n"));
```

Comment: Is there a import file for anyOf? I am getting a "Cannot resolve method" error

Comment: Which junit version are you using. If less than 4.4 then use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, but not with `assertEquals()`. Try something like:

```
Assert.assertTrue(boxes("23").equals("y") || boxes("23").equals("n"));
```

If you have multiple possible answers, a `Set` might be easier.

```
Set<String> possibleAnswers = new HashSet<>();
possibleAnswers.add("y");
possibleAnswers.add("n");
...

Assert.assertTrue(possibleAnswers.contains(boxes("23")));
```

Comment: assertj, truth or hamcrest will generate by far better messages if the expectation will not be met. The suggested solution poorly fails with: 'Expected true, but was false'

Answer (score 1):

[Assertj](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) is good at this.

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

    assertThat(boxes("23")).isIn("y", "n);
```

Big plus for assertj compared to hamcrest is easy use of code completion.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that it is possible (e.g. see @dev) it is considered to be a bad practice.

Methods returning different results on the same input must (!) contain a source of non-determinism. To resolve this - mock it correctly and there will be only one result.

An explanation for accepting multiple answers could be that the assert method is called from multiple tests just asserting a generic property of the result. Generic properties could be tested more comfortable with [Junit Theories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Theories).